# Delete specific columns in Google App Script FAST

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

below is code the delete entire columns except columns "G" and "M" using a for loop, yet the process is the way too slow, is there a way to perform it faster?

```
  var lastCol = newSheet.getLastColumn();
  var keep = [7,13]; 

  for (var col=lastCol; col > 0; col--) {
  if (keep.indexOf(col) == -1) {
  newSheet.deleteColumn(col);
                }
     }
```

Comment: Do you know how many columns you need to delete? What is the value of lastCol?

Comment: I want to delete 13 columns, I have tried using filter function but it didn't work .... `const array = newSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();                            
  const filteredArray = arr.filter(item => arr.indexOf(item) == 7 || arr.indexOf(item) == 13 );`                                                                                           but this just return rows with indices 7, 13 and I need columns with indices 7, 13...

Comment: Instead of deleting each column one by one, you can delete multiple columns using deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany). so in your case you could delete 1 - 6, 8 - 12 and 14 - last column. This way you only do 3 spreadsheet calls instead of 12+.

Comment: @AkshinJalilov sound a great solution! but aren't there any javascript equivalent that speed up the whole script?

Comment: The js part of the script take millisecond to run. What is slowing you down is every time you make a spreadsheet call. If you replace newSheet.deleteColumn(col) with console.log(col) you can see how fast it will actually run if you don't do the spreadsheet call. There is no way to speed up deleteColumn, but it will take almost same time to execute as deleteColumns, so by reducing number of times you have to trigger it you reduce your script run time.

Comment: See [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do that with the SpreadsheetApp API:

```
function test() {
  const keep = [7, 13]; // columns G and M
  const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  deleteColumns_(newSheet, keep);
}


/**
* Deletes all columns in sheet except the ones whose column numbers
* are listed in columnsToKeep.
*
* The columnsToKeep array [1, 2, 7, 13] means that columns A, B, G and M
* will remain while other columns are deleted.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet where to delete columns.
* @param {Number[]} columnsToKeep Array of column numbers to keep.
*/
function deleteColumns_(sheet, columnsToKeep) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 13 June 2022
  //   - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72600890/13045193
  const columnsToDelete = [];
  for (let i = 1, maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); i <= maxColumns; i++) {
    if (!columnsToKeep.some(columnNumber => i === columnNumber)) {
      columnsToDelete.push(i);
    }
  }
  const tuples = getRunLengths_(columnsToDelete).reverse();
  tuples.forEach(([columnStart, numColumns]) => sheet.deleteColumns(columnStart, numColumns));
}


/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.
- You want to delete all columns except for columns "G" and "M".

In this case, how about using Sheets API? When Sheets API is used, your script is as follows. I thought that when Sheets API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  var keep = [7, 13];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var lastCol = newSheet.getLastColumn(); // or newSheet.getMaxColumns()
  var sheetId = newSheet.getSheetId();
  var requests = [...Array(lastCol)].reduce((ar, _, i) => {
    if (!keep.includes(i + 1)) {
      ar.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "COLUMNS" } } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, all columns except for the columns "G" and "M" are deleted.
- From your script, `var lastCol = newSheet.getLastColumn();` is used. In this case, the data range is used. If you want to check all columns, please use `var lastCol = newSheet.getMaxColumns();` instead of it.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)

Comment: the sheet is populated every time with a different name how I  can replace that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the sheet is populated every time with a different name how I can replace that?`, if you want to change the sheet name, please modify `Sheet1` of `var sheetName = "Sheet1"`. Or, if you want to use the active sheet, please modify `var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);` to `var newSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` and remove `var sheetName = "Sheet1"`.

Comment: I mean how to get sheet name?

Comment: @Khaled Ghazi About `I mean how to retrieve sheet name?`, about how to use the active sheet, I added my previous comment. When `var newSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` is used, you can use the script without manually setting the sheet name. But, in this case, the script is run to all sheets. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).